# How to publish the Console Application (package from asp.net 5) as an Azure Web Job

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-webjobs

I have a new ASP.NET 5 application (beta 8) and I have created a console application (the new Package version). I have followed this [guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs/#convertlink) by Microsoft on publishing it to Azure Web Jobs. The guide is based on 2013 and do not use vNext, but it describes all the files, etc. that are required to publish the webjob. I have followed it and created:

- webjob-publish-settings.json
- added reference to Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish
- added webjobs-list.json (with reference to .xproj)

After I do publish my web application, no job appears (so I guess it just does not use the config properly). There is no context menu to Publish As WebJob either on the console application.

Is there any proper way to overcome it or we'll have to wait till full release of ASP.NET 5 to have it fixed and I have to create an ordinary console application meanwhile? I hope there is some workaround to publish it at least manually.

Comment: Try using the template instead. File->New->Template->Azure cloud service. Select Worker Role

Comment: There are no templates for that for ASP.NET 5 yet and it's a web job for app services, not a worker role and cloud service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no support in VS to deploy DNX WebJobs. This will come later, but until then there are still ways to deploy manually.

Related reading:

- http://ahmelsayed.com/running-dnx-based-webjobs/
- [publish dnx based WebJob with local dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33281884/publish-dnx-based-webjob-with-local-dependencies/33282610)

Comment: Do you know if there is any timeframe or roadmap when when this might happen? Seems that currently asp.net 5 with Azure lacks a lot in VS UI compared to ASP.NET 4.

Comment: ASP.NET 5 is still in beta, so indeed there are still a number of missing pieces. I don't have a data for the VS support, but it very likely will not be until 2016.

Comment: Thanks for help I was able to publish it now, but I am struggling a bit with running it now. I have troubles reading storage configuration and was only able to read it from Environment variables. Is it the only way to do it now (I have made a separate post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301089/dnx-asp-net-5-console-app-as-azure-web-job-connection-strings-configuration-no)