# DNX Webjob fails to resolve local project dependencies

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-webjobs

We have a Solution created with VS2015.1 that has 3 projects, all of them  **DNX RC1**.

```
| sln
|+---MVC6 Api
|      project.json
| +---ClassLibrary 
|      Class.cs 
|      project.json 
| \---Webjob 
      Program.cs  
      project.json
```

Both the API and Webjob reference the ClassLibrary in their project.json files.

```
 "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "ClassLibrary": "1.0.0-*"
      }
    }
  }
```

We created 2 WebApps, both tied with Continuos Integration to the Solution repo and each with a Project Application Setting that points to the API folder (in one) and the Webjob folder (in the other).

The API project gets deployed without problem, when it tries to resolve the local project dependency it works:

```
Using Project dependency ClassLibrary 1.0.0 for DNX,Version=v4.5.1
Copying source code from Project dependency ClassLibrary
    Source D:\home\site\repository\ClassLibrary\project.json
    Target D:\local\Temp\8d32044390806ef\approot\src\ClassLibrary
```

The Webjob on the other hand, fails, it tries to resolve it as a nuget remote package and fails:

```
[01/21/2016 19:47:45 > b597c3: INFO]   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/ClassLibrary/index.json
[01/21/2016 19:47:46 > b597c3: INFO]   NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/ClassLibrary/index.json 507ms
[01/21/2016 19:47:46 > b597c3: ERR ] Unable to locate Dependency ClassLibrary >= 1.0.0-*
```

This last part I had to check it through Kudu, since it's done on the first run of the WebJob apparently and not during the deploy phase (like with the API).

Running the WebJob locally works without issues.

I tried the solution in [publish dnx based WebJob with local dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33281884/publish-dnx-based-webjob-with-local-dependencies) but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking with the Product Team, the 3 project scenario won't work right now by default.

The solution described on [publish dnx based WebJob with local dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33281884/publish-dnx-based-webjob-with-local-dependencies) works for a 2 project scenario, but if you need to deploy a WebJob AND a Web App that depend on the same Class Library project and the 3 are on the same repo, you can't make the Webjob deploy from Continuous Integration.

The solution is to set Continuous Integration for your Web App (it will work by default) and manually deploy your WebJob as a zipped file.

Go into your WebJob folder and run `dnu publish`.

Go into `bin/output/approot/src/YourWebJobFolder`.

**Edit** the autogenerated **CMD file**.

Use this script by customizing line 4:

```
@ECHO OFF

:: 1. Prepare environment
SET DNX_CONSOLE_APP_PATH=Autocosmos.Trunk.Webjob
SET DNVM_CMD_PATH_FILE="%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\temp-set-envvars.cmd"

:: 2. Install DNX
CALL PowerShell -NoProfile -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ''; [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = '';$CmdPathFile='%DNVM_CMD_PATH_FILE%';& '%SCM_DNVM_PS_PATH%' " install latest
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO ERROR

:: 3. Put DNX on the path
IF EXIST %DNVM_CMD_PATH_FILE% (
    CALL %DNVM_CMD_PATH_FILE%
    DEL %DNVM_CMD_PATH_FILE%
)

call :ExecuteCmd dnx  --project "%~dp0src\%DNX_CONSOLE_APP_PATH%" --configuration Release %DNX_CONSOLE_APP_PATH% run

goto end

:ExecuteCmd
setlocal
set _CMD_=%*
call %_CMD_%
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" NEQ "0" echo Failed exitCode=%ERRORLEVEL%, command=%_CMD_%
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

:error
endlocal
echo An error has occurred during web site deployment.
call :exitSetErrorLevel
call :exitFromFunction 2>nul

:exitSetErrorLevel
exit /b 1

:exitFromFunction
()

:end
endlocal
echo Finished successfully.
```

Then **ZIP bin/output/approot** and **Upload** it to Azure.